# How to retrieve parent of a dataview?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

In sencha touch, I have a dataview inside a container.

OnItemTap, I need to reach the container and replace it's content with a new view created on the fly.

I was using dataview.getParent(),but it is returning to me a Component, this is not a container and I can't add stuff in it as intended?

How would I achieve such logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getParent().getParent() should work.